# run iexpress .sed file automatic

Tags: package, iexpress

I've created a SED file With iexpress. My question is how can I create a package Automatically with SED file using iexpress.
I'm trying (command line) :

```
iexpress mysed.sed
```

But it opens up the iexpress software And I want it create my package automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Add the /N option:

```
iexpress /n mysed.sed
```